# Conectar formulário com banco de dados

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu tenho Banco de dados chamado formulário, e uma unica tabela n_acordos.

eu preciso exibir informações do formulário em uma tabela. Não to conseguindo conectar com banco de dados.

```
<?php
 $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","formulario");
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM formulario';
 $resultado_formulario = mysqli_query($conn ,$sql);
 if($sql === FALSE) { 
   die(mysqli_error());
} 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_formulario)) {
                    echo $row['n_acordos'];
                }

                mysqli_close($conn);
?>

<p style="text-align:center"><strong><span style="font-size:120px">
<span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">
<span style="color:#FFFF00">
<span style="background-color:#000000">ACORDOS FORMALIZADOS</span></span></span></span></strong></p>

<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width:450px">
    <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4" style="text-align:center"><strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:450px"><span style="background-color:#000000"><?php $ntotalacordos=$_POST["f_total"]; echo $_POST['f_total']; ?></span></span></span></strong></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#000000"><em><strong><span style="font-size:180px">Consultor</span></strong></em></span></td>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000"><strong><span style="font-size:100px"><?php $ultimo=$_POST["f_ultimo"]; echo $_POST['f_ultimo'];
 ?></span></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif"><strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:110px"><span style="background-color:#000000"><?php $consultor1=$_POST["f_consultor1"]; echo $_POST['f_consultor1']; ?></span></span></span></strong></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000"><strong><span style="font-size:100px"><?php $penultimo = $_POST["f_penultimo"]; echo $_POST['f_penultimo']; ?></span></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif"><strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:110px"><span style="background-color:#000000"><?php $consultor2=$_POST["f_consultor2"]; echo $_POST['f_consultor2']; ?></span></span></span></strong></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><span style="color:#FF0000"><strong><span style="font-size:100px"><?php $antepenultimo=$_POST["f_antepenultimo"]; echo $_POST['f_antepenultimo']?></span></strong></span></td>
            <td><span style="font-family:tahoma,geneva,sans-serif"><strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><span style="font-size:110px"><span style="background-color:#000000"><?php $consultor3=$_POST["f_consultor3"]; echo $_POST['f_consultor3']; ?></span></span></span></strong></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<p style="text-align:center"><strong><span style="font-size:80px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="color:#FFFF00"><span style="background-color:#000000">TOTAL DE PARCELAS</span></span></span></span></strong></p>

<p style="text-align:center"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif"><span style="font-size:180px"><span style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0)"><strong><span style="color:#FFFFFF"> R$<?php $consultor3=$_POST["f_valor"]; echo $_POST['f_valor']; ?></span></strong></span></span></span></p>
```

Comment: Qual erro está dando?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\envio\recebe.php on line 8

Comment: Este erro acontece porque o seu objeto `$conn` não foi inicializado corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Tente uma conexão da seguinte maneira:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('HOST', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'NAME_TABLE');

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table ");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

 echo $row['n_acordos'];
 }
```

Comment: esse utf8 na linha: mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
 seria o que?

Comment: E a orientação do conjunto de caracteres padrão do cliente.

Comment: eu fiz alteração que voce pediu,nao apareceu mais erro. so que ainda nao ta mostrando informações do formulario na tabela que eu desejo que apareça. vou te manda meu formulario. sera que eu tenho que coloca alguma coisa na minha tabela formulario para registrar na tabela as informações que eu desejo?

Answer (score 0):

## ACORDOS FORMALIZADOS

```
<body>
</br>

    <form name="f_cad" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="recebe.php">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Nº Total de Acordos</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number_format" class="form-control" name="f_total" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Total de Parcelas</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number_format" class="form-control" name="f_valor" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Nº Último Acordo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number_format" class="form-control" name="f_ultimo" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Nome do consultor</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_consultor1" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Nº Penúltimo Acordo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number_format" class="form-control" name="f_penultimo" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Nome do consultor</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_consultor2" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="firstName">Nº Antepenultimo Acordo</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="number_format" class="form-control" name="f_antepenultimo" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="lastName">Nome do consultor</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="f_consultor3" placeholder="Digite Aqui" value="" required />
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-8 col-sm-4">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Atualizar">
        </div>
    </div>
    </center>
    </div>

    </form>
```